# What is crater's influence on laser ablation?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, laser, plasma-physics, experimental-technology

In many laser ablation experiments (especially Pulsed Laser Deposition), target is moving to avoid crater formation. But I can't find any source that says why it is needed to avoid it. So why is crater so unwelcome?

Comment: Don't you want *smooth* surfaces? At least, that was our goal when I did MAPLE/PLD in my senior lab in undergrad.

Comment: @KyleKanos I want to produce smooth surface. But why do I need to shoot laser at smooth surface?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment there means. It's been many years since I did PLD, but if I recall correctly, we shot a laser at a target so that the a solute in the target would ablate onto the surface of the substrate. Our goal was studying the morphology dependence on solvent/solute ratios.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm going to deposite thin layer of aluminium on my substrate, therefore my laser ablates aluminium target. My boss told me to make target rotate, so the beam won't create a crater, since ablation from crater is different than ablation from smooth surface. However I can't find a source that tells what is the role of crater in ablation process.

Comment: Oh, you're concerned with the target crater and not a crater on the substrate. I'm not 100% sure, but I would suspect it could be due to the angle of the ejected Al. Burning a hole could cause it to fly the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Crater could enhance the LIBS signal up to an optimum depth and then for deeper craters the signal decreases. See below for references. Then if you keep the laser position on the sample unchanged, after a number of shots the signal degrades.

https://www.osapublishing.org/as/abstract.cfm?uri=as-59-7-853
https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-20-106-A1011

Answer (score 2):

As you might know, one of the most important factors to control in a laser ablation process is the laser power.

It is therefore extremely important that the power on the sample is kept constant during the process. The formation of a crater puts the surface at a different distance (or maybe changing the focus, if you are using a parabolic mirror) thus changing the power.

Also, in a crater the angle between the laser beam and the surface is different, which also as an influence on the ablation process.